# How to force my AJAX-called elements to append in the very same order as I specified in my array?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a question and I'm very surprised that I've never seen any script implementing such a technique, but I can't solve it on my own, so I need a clue. To see what I want, please check out this basic page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<style>

#loading{

display:none;

position: fixed;

width:500px;

height:200px;

top: 50%;

left: 50%;

margin-top: -100px;

margin-left: -250px;

z-index: 1;

border:black thin solid;

background-color: gold;}

</style>

<script src="path/to/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.click').click(function () {

        $("#content").empty();

        var src = $(this).attr('data-source').split(';');
        var l = src.length;
        $("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){
        $(this).html("Loading, please wait...").show();
        }).ajaxStop(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        });
        if (src.length >= 1 && src.length <= 5) {
            $.get(src[0].substring(src[0].lastIndexOf('@') + 1), {}, function (data) {
                var $response = $('<div />').html(data);
                $('#content').append($response.find(src[0].substring(0, src[0].lastIndexOf('@'))));
            }, 'html').complete(function () {
                $('#loading').html('Loaded: 1. Total: ' + l);
                if (src.length >= 2) {
                    $.get(src[1].substring(src[1].lastIndexOf('@') + 1), {}, function (data) {
                        var $response = $('<div />').html(data);
                        $('#content').append($response.find(src[1].substring(0, src[1].lastIndexOf('@'))));
                    }, 'html').complete(function () {
                        $('#loading').html('Loaded: 2. Total: ' + l);
                        if (src.length >= 3) {
                            $.get(src[2].substring(src[2].lastIndexOf('@') + 1), {}, function (data) {
                                var $response = $('<div />').html(data);
                                $('#content').append($response.find(src[2].substring(0, src[2].lastIndexOf('@'))));
                            }, 'html').complete(function () {
                                $('#loading').html('Loaded: 3. Total: ' + l);
                                if (src.length >= 4) {
                                    $.get(src[3].substring(src[3].lastIndexOf('@') + 1), {}, function (data) {
                                        var $response = $('<div />').html(data);
                                        $('#content').append($response.find(src[3].substring(0, src[3].lastIndexOf('@'))));
                                    }, 'html').complete(function () {
                                        $('#loading').html('Loaded: 4. Total: ' + l);
                                        if (src.length >= 5) {
                                                         $.get(src[4].substring(src[4].lastIndexOf('@') + 1), {}, function (data) {
                                                var $response = $('<div />').html(data);
                                           $('#content').append($response.find(src[4].substring(0, src[4].lastIndexOf('@'))));
        }, 'html').complete(function () {
        $('#loading').html('Loaded: 5. Total: ' + l);
        });
        }
        });
        }
        });
        }
        });
        }
        });
        } 
        });
        });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<span data-source="#part1, #part3, #part4@page1.html;#part2@page2.html;#part5@page1.html" class="click">Click me</span>
<div id="content">
</div>
<div id="loading">Loading, please wait...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

That is, the elements are loading strictly in the order that I specified in my "data-source" attribute.
This script seems to work as I expect, but the problem is that I don't want to "manually" write a separate function for every possible length!!! I want a script that will do this job automatically! I tried this:

```
   jQuery.each(src, function (i) {
            $.get(src[i].substring(src[i].lastIndexOf('@') + 1), {}, function (data) {
                var $response = $('<div />').html(data);
                var $ids = $response.find(src[i].substring(0, src[i].lastIndexOf('@')));
                $('#content').append($ids);
            }, 'html').complete(function () {
                $('#loading').html('Loaded: ' + (i + 1) + '. Total:' + l);
            });
        });
```

But in this case, due to the very nature of AJAX and the fact that jQuery.each is not equivalent to an infinite .complete(function () {... .complete(function () {... .complete(function () {... , the elements will not append in the same order that I specified, especially if they come from the same page. And if I write my data-source attribute as "page 1.html #part1, #part2" and use something like this:

```
    jQuery.each(src, function (i) {
            $('<div />').attr('class', 'container').appendTo($('#content')).load(src[i], function() {
    $('#loading').html('Loaded: ' + (i + 1) + '. Total:' + l);
    });
        });
```

The elements seem to append in a right order, and they do it the way I can't understand: one just shifts down another, taking its place between the two already existing elements! But I can't imagine where that HTML in my loading message comes from, it may just show that the pages are loading from last to first. I also tried to make use of ajaxComplete event and manipulate with the "data" attribute after my first Ajax call, but got no results.

So, is ajaxComplete equal to .complete(function () {... .complete(function () {... .complete(function () {... ? If it is, how can I tell to the script: "Start with the first element of this array, forget about the others. When you're done, switch to the next... and so on, till the end"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest following solution with recursion:

```
var i = 0; 
var load = function (index) {
    $.get(src[index].substring(src[index].lastIndexOf('@') + 1), {}, function (data) {    
            var $response = $('<div />').html(data);    
            var $ids = $response.find(src[index].substring(0, src[index].lastIndexOf('@')));    
            $('#content').append($ids);    
        }, 'html').complete(function () {    
            $('#loading').html('Loaded: ' + (index + 1) + '. Total:' + l);
                          if(index +=1){
                load(index += 1); //recursion
                          }
        });
}
load(i);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this code seems not to complete my task, throwing a "src[index] is undefined" error at the end... How to get rid of it?

Comment: I changed the code. Added a check before firing load(index += 1).